# Swift//How can I add an action to a button inside a custom view class, where the action need to access a tableView Cell property?

Tags: swift, uitableview, addtarget

I made a custom UIView class, it has a viwe and inside that view there is a button. The problem is implement the action for the button, the action that i need is when press that button a label textcolor inside a table view cell should changed to another color. How I can make that action work.

I tried to make a delegate and set it inside the tableview controller but is did not work :(

Comment: bearinf in mind that the custom view show when press a navigationbarbutton for a tableview controller

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.